# URL Map an entire namespace using rack mount?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have two modular Sinatra rack based applications: `core.rb` & `project.rb`:

```
# core.rb
class Core < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end

# project.rb
class Project < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "A snazzy little Sinatra project I wish to showcase."
  end
  get "/foo" do
    "If you see this, congratulations."
  end
end
```

My goal is simply to map the entire `/projects` namespace to the `Project` class, wheras everything else is handled by the `Core` class. I found that you can do this to a limited extent in 2 ways:

```
# config.ru
require "./core.rb"
require "./projects.rb"

map "/projects" do
  # Method #1: Using Sinatra's built-in Middleware
  use Project
  # Method #2: Using Rack::Cascade
  run Rack::Cascade.new( [Project, Core] )
end
run Core
```

Both of the methods I tried above have the same effect. The routes `/` and `/projects` show up correctly, however when  going to `/projects/foo` it throws an error which states it can't find the `/foo` route in my main `core.rb` file - which is **NOT** what I want. In other words it's looking for my `/foo` route in the wrong file :(

So, is it possible to map across the entire `/projects` namespace using rack-mount? And no, adding "/projects/" to all my routes in `project.rb` is not an option here I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `config.ru` file seems to work okay when I test it, but it looks a little confused. Here’s a simpler example that achieves the same thing:

```
map "/projects" do
  run Project # note run, not use
end
run Core
```

Now any request where the path starts with `/projects` will be routed to the `Project` app, and all other will go to `Core`, which is associated with the root path automatically.

Comment: Ahh, didn't release the solution was that simple. So what's the difference between `run` and `use`? And yes, using `run` ended up working perfectly, thank you.