# Sinatra: How to set namespace for base class

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How to organize controllers hierarchy so that get something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Application
  set :namespace, '/api' # ???
end

class UsersController < AplicationController
  namespace '/users' do
    # /api/users/show
    get '/show' do
      # blablabla
    end
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  namespace '/posts' do
    # /api/posts/show
    get '/posts' do
      # blablabla
    end
  end
end
```

I'm mostly worked with Rails and dont know it is possible to do in Sinatra.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change one word:

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
```

From [Sinatra Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920019664.do):

> Route Inheritance Not only settings, but every aspect of a Sinatra
>   class will be inherited by its subclasses. This includes defined
>   routes, all the error handlers, extensions, middleware, and so on.
>   But most importantly, it will be inherited just the way methods are
>   inherited. In case you should define a route for a class after having
>   subclassed that class, the route will also be available in the
>   subclass.

If you're looking for namespacing of the HTML route sort and not just the Ruby sort, then take a look at [Sinatra Contrib](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib) which includes Sinatra Namespace.

If you do use Sinatra Namespace, you'd probably want to change one more word:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  namespace '/posts' do
    # /api/posts/show
    get '/' do # otherwise the route would be /posts/posts
      # blablabla
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how should I define ApplicationController with global namespace?

Comment: By global namespace, do you mean you'd have a route like "/api/v1" in the ApplicationController and everything inheriting from that would also have its routes prepended with "/api/v1" ?

Comment: Best way to do that, in my opinion, is to [use Rack map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21461913/335847). Use Sinatra Namespace for extending that.